# Undefined property: Session::$session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, controller

Setting data not working ? Where's my problem?
I load library only in this controller for practice but I'm receiving this error.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Message: Undefined property: Session::$session

```
<?php 

class Session extends CI_Controller {
    
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }
    
    public function index() {
                
        $newdata = array(
                'username'  => 'johndoe',
                'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                'logged_in' => TRUE
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you set encryption key in order to autoload or load session in controller functions? Also change your classname and then check. You should not use `Session` as your controller name.

Comment: thanks bro the problem was in the class name ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class name is conflicting with the library name. When you are calling `$this->session->set_userdata()` you are actually trying to access a property within the current class since it is called session.

The only way around this problem is to rename your class to something other than `session`.